# StringConcat for APIM Policy set-query-parameter

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I need to join strings for an backend api, front api is just accepting an Id value such: ProjectId while the backend request is in the form a www.formUrlencoded string, and needs the request to be in the form for data="{Query":"Project(ProjectId=@(context.Variables["ProjectId"])}.

The string set in the policy definition is "{Query":"Project(ProjectId='@(context. Variables["ProjectId"])'", however when looking at the trace, actual string is :
{Query":"Project(ProjectId=@(context.Variables["ProjectId"])}

It should be
{Query":"Project(ProjectId='1234567') I have tried a number of combinations, I can't get this working. Any suggestions, greatly appreciated.

```
  <set-query-parameter name="data" exists-action="override">
        <value>{"Query":"Project(ProjectId=@(context.Variables["ProjectId"])"}</value>
  </set-query-parameters>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the policy given below to pass the Query string value as `{Query":"Project(ProjectId='1234567')"}`.

**Policy**-

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-variable name="ProjectId" value="1234567" />
        <set-query-parameter name="data" exists-action="override">
            <value>@($"{{\"Query\":\"Project(ProjectId='{context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("ProjectId")}')\"}}")</value>
        </set-query-parameter>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

This policy will add the query string parameter to the backend URL as shown below-

[image]